# Trying to decode bitmap from image file and send to the server

Tags: android

I basically want to hide the imagesthe user clicks in my app from the user in the gallery, display them in a small imageview and send it to the server. I am doing it the below way. However Bitmap Factory decode gives me a null bitmap I dont know why. Any help would be appreciated.

For creating file to save image to and opening camera intent;

```
public void openCamera(View view) {
    PermissionsClass.checkPermissions(DIalogActivity.this, AppConfig.REQ_WRITE_ACCESS);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(DIalogActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            //resizeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DIalogActivity.this,
                    "com.example.sandithaa.nfcreader.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            Log.i("photouri", String.valueOf(photoURI));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }


            }

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera cannot be opened.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


    }
    }
```

For creating the file:

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {


    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.i("filepathin createbefore", mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}
```

For uploading to the server :

```
private void uploadFile() {
    final String path;


    Log.i("uplaod pdf", "pdf");
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomNo = r.nextInt(100000000 + 1);
    String name = "IMG" + randomNo;

    //getting the actual path of the image

    //  path = FilePath.getPath(this, photoURI);
    //    Log.i("path is",path);


    Log.i("current parh", mCurrentPhotoPath);

    try {
        final String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Log.i("in uplaod 1", String.valueOf(priority.getSelectedItem()));
        Log.i("proti", incidentEt.getText().toString());
        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, "http://technobyteinfo.in/filter-coffee/uploadAll.php")
                .addFileToUpload(mCurrentPhotoPath, "pdf") //Adding file
                .addParameter("name", name)
                .addParameter("description", incidentEt.getText().toString().trim())
                .addParameter("priority" +
                        "", priority.getSelectedItem().toString())
                .addParameter("time", time)
                .addParameter("longitude", MySharedPreferences.retrievePreferences("longitude", getApplicationContext(), "00.00"))
                .addParameter("latitude", MySharedPreferences.retrievePreferences("latitude", getApplicationContext(), "00.00"))
                .addParameter("deviceid", GetDeviceId.getMyAndroidDeviceId(getApplicationContext()))
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .setDelegate(new UploadStatusDelegate() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, Exception exception) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "File could not be uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("exceptipn", exception.getMessage());


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse) {

                        Log.i("error is", serverResponse.getBodyAsString());
                        JSONObject jObj = null;
                        try {
                            jObj = new JSONObject(serverResponse.getBodyAsString());
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                            if (error == false) {


                                Toast.makeText(context, "Details saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "File could not be uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(Context context, UploadInfo uploadInfo) {

                    }
                })
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Trying to compress the images this way:

```
    public void compressImage() {
                try {
                    OutputStream outStream = null;

                   Log.i("imagefiename",imageFileName);
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 8;
                     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileName ,bmOptions);

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, outStream);

                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();


                    Log.i("file path compress", mCurrentPhotoPath);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.i("exception", e.toString());
                }
            }
```

My onActivityResult after camera intent comes back:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        compressImage();
        Picasso.get().load(photoURI).resize(300,300).into(imageView);



    }
```

Comment: 1) don't ignore the exceptions. `try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File

    }`. 2) you don't need to *create* a file where you want the image to be put by camera. You only need to specify name and path.

Comment: How do I specify just the name and path for it?

Comment: it's a global variable used in the createImageFile method.

Comment: in your `createImageFile` you build a path/name of the file, and use `createTempFIle`. Don't create a file.

Comment: what are you getting in this mCurrentPhotoPath?